# Write a Text File to specific rows of a Datagridview

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, text-files

I have a Datagridview (dgvMaster) and a comma separated text file that i am using as a database (each line starts with an ID number and these are unique).  A button (btnLoadSeries) loads the file shown in a textbox (txtseriestoload).
The Text File looks like:

```
1,joe,smith
2,john,doe
30,charlie,brown
```

What I would like is to be able to write the row with "1,joe,smith" to row #1, and "30,charlie,brown" to row 30, and so on.  I have tried a few different ideas but I am a self taught VB user. Here is my current code and it fills the dgvmaster with the number of rows from the file and shows the row number but then adds the data after that.  I have tried to simply add 5000 rows even though my file will never contain an id greater than 5000 still with no luck.  This is a first time post for me so please be kind!

```
   Private Sub btnLoadSeries_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLoadSeries.Click
    dgvMaster.Rows.Clear()
    Dim TextLine As String = ""
    Dim SplitLine() As String
    Dim fname As String = txtSeriestoLoad.Text

    'Count the lines of the file.  May change to a fixed number.
    Dim lineCount = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fname).Length

    'Set the number of rows
    dgvMaster.RowCount = lineCount + 1

    'Show row number
    Dim rownumber As Integer
    For rownumber = 0 To lineCount
        dgvMaster.Rows(rownumber).HeaderCell.Value = (rownumber).ToString
    Next rownumber

    'write file to dgvmaster
    If System.IO.File.Exists(fname) = True Then
        Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(fname)
        Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
            TextLine = objReader.ReadLine()
            SplitLine = Split(TextLine, ",")
            Me.dgvMaster.Rows.Add(SplitLine)
        Loop
    Else
        MsgBox("File Does Not Exist")
    End If



End Sub
```

Comment: In a real database, which a CSV is not, you arent supposed to care where the data resides...you usually dont even know.  Add the data as needed then sort the DGV by that column and it will put them in order

Comment: What about row 3,4,5,...,29? All numbers exist in the files? What about spaces in the file, are spaces only appear after id? And what about commas? All rows have 2 commas and both name and family are present?

Comment: Reza, The textfile will always contain the same number of "columns" and be separated with a comma so in the case of a row that does not contain a first name the file will show "4,,smith".  I do not care if rows which do not contain data (3-29 in my above example) are shown.  Plutonix, i am hoping to then add data using select row and that is why i am hoping to have the ID number match the row number.

Comment: You can load the file content and split the content using space to get rows. Then split each row using comma to get columns and then add them to grid. It's the main idea. As a good example I created a Person class to implement the idea in a more flexible way but you can add your items directly to the `DataGridView` that I don't recommend.

Comment: `I do not care if rows which do not contain data (3-29 in my above example)` then they have no reason to be in the "database" until they do have data.  Note the name "DATAbase"

Comment: Plutonix, i completely understand and appreciate your feedback.  As i mentioned i am a self taught VB user and have very limited skills.  If that was the only way than i had no issue with it.  I know this is not a true database but it is what i need to work with right now so any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Let me clarify.  I want to write the line in my text file to the appropriate line in the DataGridView.  This will allow id#101 to be in Row 101 of the datagridview.  I want to do this to allow for me to reference it later by simply searching for row 101 of the datagridview .  This would also be why i have no issue with rows in the DataGridView being blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load the file content and split the content using `Environment.NewLine` to get rows. Then split each row using comma to get columns and then add them to grid.

For example:

```
Dim content = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("File Path")
Dim rows = content.Split(Environment.NewLine).Select(Function(Row)
                                         Dim Cells = Row.Split(",")
                                         Return New Person With
                                         {
                                             .Id = Integer.Parse(Cells(0)),
                                             .FirstName = Cells(1),
                                             .LastName = Cells(2)
                                         }
                                     End Function).OrderBy(Function(x) x.Id).ToList()
Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = rows
```

Or if you need to add/edit/delete rows:

```
Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = New BindingList(Of Person)(rows)
```

And here is the `Person` class:

```
Public Class Person
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property FirstName As String
    Public Property LastName As String
End Class
```

Comment: I have added the person class and created a new button on my form and pasted the two code examples (changed file path and datagridview to match mine) but at run time i got an error:An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Comment: Here is my test data: `1,x,y 2,, 3,a,b` that works properly. Probably you have some invalid id or an additional space somewhere. Trace the program and use breakpoint to find the problem. The code is working properly. If you are not familiar with linq you can use a for loop instead simply. If you learn the main idea the rest is easy :)

Comment: Thanks Reza, my text file is not separated by spaces but rather by lines.

Comment: No problem, instead of space use `Environment.NewLine`

Comment: Reza, my text file is separated by lines not by spaces.  I just realized that my intial question had it broken into lines but when i posted the question it put the data onto one line.  I will try to correct the initial post.  Apologies!

Comment: I Edited your question to show the input with line breaks. Also I edited the answer to use `Environment.NewLine`

Comment: Everything worked and using my 3 line sample file 3 lines were written.  1, 2, and 30.  is the line with 30 in it now row 30 of the dgv? Is there a way to show the headercell vaule (which i think would be the row number?

Comment: When the DGV has only 3 rows, how could it be the row number 30. You can see Id Column in DGV, if you don't like `Id` for that property name, use `Index` for example.

Comment: Let me clarify.  I want to write the line in my text file to the appropriate line in the DataGridView.  This will allow id#101 to be in Row 101 of the datagridview.  I want to do this to allow for me to reference it later by simply searching for row 101 of the datagridview .  This would also be why i have no issue with rows in the DataGridView being blank.

Comment: You don't need to do that, you can simply refer those items using `Id` property and `Id` Column value. Inserting empty rows is not a good idea.

Comment: What if i then need to add information to an id that is between those numbers?  i.e. if i needed to add information to the datagridview for id #10 in my example.

Comment: You have lost the whole idea. You have Id column and you can simply add a new row with new values for example `10`,`Parker`,`O'Connel` in the DataGridView. To be able to add new Items, you should bind the grid to `BindingList(Of Person)`

Comment: Unfortunately you are asking for doing a wrong job that I can surely add another part to the answer that performs exactly what you need. But I think it will mislead future readers. The question asks for reading existing items from a file and show them in a grid. That I believe this post answers the question.

Comment: If you have any extra question, too keep the thread clean, you can ask your new question in a different post :)

Comment: Reza, thank you again for the help your answer does perform the task of writing a text file to a grid view but my initial post asked to write a textfile to specific rows as that is what i thought i needed.  Your answer clarifies that i was incorrect and i appreciate you taking the time to help me understand!

Answer (score 0):

The following reads in a text file in the executable path (feel free to change it) into a DataTable which is used as the DataSource of a BindingSource (see comments) then the BindingSource is setup to be the DataSource of a DataGridView where there are no columns defined. After the data is loaded I use the BindingSource to find and position to a row in the DataGridView based on the field ID. Button1 write the current data back to the same file. Button2 shows how to get the first name field for the current row in the DataGridView.Button3, here we change a field value from the DataTable. Button4 we position to a field based on a search then position to it if found.

I keeped control named generic on purpose, feel free to rename them.

If you need column names that would be easy to add in too.

Of course we could use other containers for the data e.g. a List(Of T) but in this case seems the following works for the task at hand just fine.

If there is a chance the ID is missing some assertion would be needed but sounds like this should be there, if not use Integer.TryParse first.

Code

```
Public Class Form1
    ' provides easy method to find, position, view, add, edit, remove
    Private bs As New BindingSource
    Private fileName As String = IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "TextFile1.txt")
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ' make sure file exists
        If IO.File.Exists(fileName) Then
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn With {.ColumnName = "ID", .DataType = GetType(Integer)})
            dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn With {.ColumnName = "FirstName", .DataType = GetType(String)})
            dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn With {.ColumnName = "LastName", .DataType = GetType(String)})

            ' cycle through data and add rows to data table
            Using Reader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(fileName)

                Reader.TextFieldType = Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
                Reader.Delimiters = New String() {","}

                Dim Row As String()

                While Not Reader.EndOfData
                    Try
                        Row = Reader.ReadFields()
                        dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {CInt(Row(0)), Row(1), Row(2)})
                    Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
                        MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message & " is invalid.  Skipping")
                    End Try
                End While
            End Using

            bs.DataSource = dt
            DataGridView1.DataSource = bs

            ' let's see if id 3 exists and if so move to it
            Dim pos As Integer = bs.Find("ID", 3)
            If pos > -1 Then
                bs.Position = pos
            End If

        End If

    End Sub
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Write current data to file
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="sender"></param>
    ''' <param name="e"></param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If bs.DataSource IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim dt As DataTable = CType(bs.DataSource, DataTable)
            Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
            For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
                sb.AppendLine(String.Join(",", row.ItemArray))
            Next
            IO.File.WriteAllText(fileName, sb.ToString)
        End If
    End Sub
    ''' <summary>
    ''' example how to get back a field value
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="sender"></param>
    ''' <param name="e"></param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        If bs.DataSource IsNot Nothing Then
            If bs.Current IsNot Nothing Then
                MessageBox.Show(CType(bs.Current, DataRowView).Row.Field(Of String)("FirstName"))
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Change a field value
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="sender"></param>
    ''' <param name="e"></param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        If bs.DataSource IsNot Nothing Then
            If bs.Current IsNot Nothing Then
                If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox1.Text) Then
                    CType(bs.Current, DataRowView).Row.SetField(Of String)("LastName", TextBox1.Text)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Find and position based on a field value
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="sender"></param>
    ''' <param name="e"></param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        If bs.DataSource IsNot Nothing Then
            If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox2.Text) Then
                Dim pos As Integer = bs.Find("FirstName", TextBox2.Text)
                If pos > -1 Then
                    bs.Position = pos
                Else
                    MessageBox.Show(TextBox2.Text & " not found")
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Sample text file

```
1,Karen,Payne
2,Kevin,Gallagher
3,Mary,Williams
4,Lisa,Miller
5,Betty,Moore
6,Laura,Jackson
7,Jon,Wright
```

Lastly, if you wanted to export from the DataGridView here is a language extension method (extension method go into code modules)

```
IO.File.WriteAllLines(fileName, DataGridView1.DelimitedRows(","))
```

...

```
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
<Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
Public Function ExportRows(ByVal sender As DataGridView, ByVal Delimiter As String) As String()
    Return (From row In sender.Rows Where Not DirectCast(row, DataGridViewRow).IsNewRow Let RowItem = String.Join(Delimiter, Array.ConvertAll(DirectCast(row, DataGridViewRow).Cells.Cast(Of DataGridViewCell).ToArray, Function(c As DataGridViewCell) If(c.Value Is Nothing, "", c.Value.ToString))) Select RowItem).ToArray
End Function
```

**New sample**
This version creates data rows first before reading in all lines.

text file

```
1,Karen,Payne
2,Kevin,Gallagher
3,Mary,Williams
4,Lisa,Miller
78,Bill,Jenkins
10,Jim,Clime
5,Betty,Moore
6,Laura,Jackson
7,Jon,Wright
```

Revised code

```
Public Class Form1
    ' provides easy method to find, position, view, add, edit, remove
    Private bs As New BindingSource
    Private fileName As String = IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "TextFile1.txt")
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        If IO.File.Exists(fileName) Then
            Dim Identifier As Integer = 0
            Dim dt As New DataTable

            ' row with identifier but we are hiding it, feel free to show
            dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn With {
                           .ColumnName = "ID",
                           .DataType = GetType(Integer),
                           .AutoIncrement = True,
                           .AutoIncrementSeed = 1,
                           .ColumnMapping = MappingType.Hidden
                       }
            )

            ' optional, show # in front of ID - feel free to discard
            dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn With
                           {
                               .ColumnName = "Identifier",
                               .DataType = GetType(String),
                               .Expression = "'#' + ID"
                            }
            )

            dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn With
                           {
                               .ColumnName = "FirstName",
                               .DataType = GetType(String)
                           }
            )
            dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn With
                           {
                               .ColumnName = "LastName",
                               .DataType = GetType(String)
                           }
            )

            Dim HighIdentifier As Integer = 0
            Dim IdentifierList As New List(Of Integer)

            ' get highest identifier
            Using Reader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(fileName)
                Reader.TextFieldType = Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
                Reader.Delimiters = New String() {","}

                Dim Row As String()
                While Not Reader.EndOfData
                    Row = Reader.ReadFields()
                    If Integer.TryParse(Row(0), Identifier) Then
                        IdentifierList.Add(Identifier)
                    End If
                End While
            End Using

            HighIdentifier = IdentifierList.Max

            ' add rows equal to highest identifier
            For x As Integer = 0 To HighIdentifier - 1
                dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {Nothing, "", ""})
            Next

            bs.DataSource = dt

            ' cycle through data and add rows to data table
            Using Reader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(fileName)

                Reader.TextFieldType = Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
                Reader.Delimiters = New String() {","}

                Dim Row As String()
                Dim Index As Integer = 0

                While Not Reader.EndOfData
                    Try

                        Row = Reader.ReadFields()

                        ' find/update row if first field is truly an integer
                        ' we could go another route rather than BindingSource.Find
                        ' so feel free to change it e.g. DataTable.Find, DataTable.Select
                        If Integer.TryParse(Row(0), Identifier) Then
                            Index = bs.Find("ID", Identifier)
                            If Index > -1 Then
                                bs.Position = Index
                                CType(bs.Current, DataRowView).Row.SetField(Of String)("FirstName", Row(1))
                                CType(bs.Current, DataRowView).Row.SetField(Of String)("LastName", Row(2))
                            End If
                        End If
                    Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
                        MessageBox.Show("Line " & ex.Message & " is invalid.  Skipping")
                    End Try
                End While
            End Using


            DataGridView1.DataSource = bs
            bs.Position = 0

        End If

    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Write current data to file
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="sender"></param>
    ''' <param name="e"></param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If bs.DataSource IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim dt As DataTable = CType(bs.DataSource, DataTable)
            Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
            For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
                sb.AppendLine(String.Join(",", row.ItemArray))
            Next
            IO.File.WriteAllText(fileName, sb.ToString)
        End If

        ' IO.File.WriteAllLines(fileName, DataGridView1.DelimitedRows(","))
    End Sub
    ''' <summary>
    ''' example how to get back a field value
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="sender"></param>
    ''' <param name="e"></param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        If bs.DataSource IsNot Nothing Then
            If bs.Current IsNot Nothing Then
                MessageBox.Show(CType(bs.Current, DataRowView).Row.Field(Of String)("FirstName"))
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Change a field value
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="sender"></param>
    ''' <param name="e"></param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        If bs.DataSource IsNot Nothing Then
            If bs.Current IsNot Nothing Then
                If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox1.Text) Then
                    CType(bs.Current, DataRowView).Row.SetField(Of String)("LastName", TextBox1.Text)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Find and position based on a field value
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="sender"></param>
    ''' <param name="e"></param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        If bs.DataSource IsNot Nothing Then
            If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox2.Text) Then
                Dim pos As Integer = bs.Find("FirstName", TextBox2.Text)
                If pos > -1 Then
                    bs.Position = pos
                Else
                    MessageBox.Show(TextBox2.Text & " not found")
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Parker, it's at the top of the code. Also I have the VS2013 project here https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=A3D5A9A9A28080D1!884&authkey=!AN4Zly9yVzOuPLg&ithint=file%2czip with no binaries so it needs a build before trying it.

Comment: Thansk Karen for the project but let me clarify.  I want to write the line in my text file to the appropriate line in the DataGridView.  This will allow id#101 to be in Row 101 of the datagridview.  I want to do this to allow for me to reference it later by simply searching for row 101 of the datagridview .  This would also be why i have no issue with rows in the DataGridView being blank.

Comment: Try the new sample I just posted in my original reply which starts at the bolded text.